# How to pass a string to ofstream::open for the file name

Tags: c++

This is my first C++ app. I'm using Visual C++ 2010 Express. I'm trying to write a console program that will write the line "alive" to the file alive.txt on my WD USB hard drive every 10 seconds to prevent the drive from spinning down.  I want the program to prompt me for the drive letter, and then use that to tell the program where the file is located.  This works:

```
while (true)
{
Sleep(5000);
cout << "Past sleep";
ofstream AliveFile;
AliveFile.open ("j:\\alive.txt");
AliveFile << "alive" << endl;
AliveFile.close();
} 
return 0;
```

But when I get the drive letter from the console input and save the path to a string and pass that to AliveFile.open it doesn't work:

```
string DriveLetter;
cout << "What is the drive letter for the drive you want to keep awake?" << endl;
getline(cin, DriveLetter);
cin.clear();
string Path;
Path = "\"" + DriveLetter + ":\\alive.txt\"";
cout << Path << endl;

while (true)
{
Sleep(10000);
ofstream AliveFile;
AliveFile.open ( Path );
AliveFile << "alive" << endl;
AliveFile.close();
} 
return 0;
```

The path comes out fine when i cout << Path so I do not understand why AliveFile.open(Path) does not work.

Comment: Are you sure that `DriveLetter` is a string of exactly one letter? Did you check its length? Did you try to debug your program with a debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Path = "\"" + DriveLetter + ":\\alive.txt\"";  // Why adding \ before the root.
```

Try -

```
Path = DriveLetter + ":\\alive.txt\";
```

Comment: Ah that makes sense.  I was thinking I needed the quotes around it.  Thank you!

Comment: Usually only need the quotes if you are constructing an argument string to use in a system or shell call.