# ofstream writing data to file: How do I pass a previously defined string as the filename

Tags: c++, string, csv, ofstream, qstring

I have a program that I have written with C++, OpenCV and Qt, where I am trying to write data to a csv file. In my Qt Widget I have created a QFileDialog that allows me to choose where to save the csv file.

This path is then stored as a QString, and converted to a std::string as follows;

```
std::string OutputFileName = OutputFile.toUtf8().constData();
```

I then try to pass this std::string to my ofstream::open function as follows:

```
ofstream CSVFile;
CSVFile.open(OutputFileName);
```

And there lies the problem; it refuses to compile, giving the error

> no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ofstream >::open(std::string&)'

I'm very new to programming and thus I have no idea what exactly the problem is here. I have tried looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9284349/how-to-pass-a-string-to-ofstreamopen-for-the-file-name), but from what I can tell that is a Windows specific solution, and I am using OSX.

Can anyone tell me how I can successfully pass the filepath stored in the QString to the CSVFile.open() term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in C++03, [ofstream::open](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/open) takes `const char*` parameter.

If OutputFileName is std::string.

Try:

```
CSVFile.open(OutputFileName.c_str());
```

If outputFileName is Qstring

```
CSVFile.open(OutputFileName.toStdString().c_str());
```

See [QString::toStdString](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#toStdString) reference